# XPATH for dialog input text field?

Tags: xpath

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeI6d.jpg)
[Jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqINP.jpg)
Could you help me to show xpath of the below html code?

Thanks you!

HTML code:

```
<div class="p-ui-textinputinputdata" style="display: none;"/>
<input class="p-ui-textinputinputobject inputwidget-inputobject p-ui-inputlimiter" style="display: inline-block;" tabindex="201"/>
```

Comment: xpath to capture what?  input value? attribute?

Comment: Xpath to input value.
Html also show .//*[@id='ui-id-209']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/input
And I tried to use below code:
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ui-id-209']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/input")).SendKeys("Test");
And it show error

Comment: ok.  you are comparing a single tag vs the location of the tag inside an html block.  can you change your question to include in all html surrounding these two tags?

Comment: My question was changed. Sorry my English is not good. ^^

Comment: no.  sorry, I mean ALL html.  <html><body> etc....  Thanks.

Comment: I have just added Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//input[contains(@class, 'p-ui-textinputinputobject')]/@value
```

or you can use JQUERY:

```
$("input.p-ui-textinputinputobject").val();
```

OPTION 2:

```
js.ExecuteScript(@"jQuery('input.p-ui-textinputinputobject').val('Test')");
```

Comment: I tried to use below code but it didn't work
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'p-ui-textinputinputobject')]/@value")).SendKeys("Test");

Comment: Just remove the **/@value** from the end of the Xpath and it'll work, You need the element itself and not the attribute **value**

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'p-ui-textinputinputobject')]")).SendKeys("Test");

still not work :((

Comment: ok.  if you are inserting text....I suggest JQUERY.  `$("input.p-ui-textinputinputobject").val("Test");`  this should enter it in.  try that.  I have one more option if that fails.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                URL jqueryUrl = Resources.getResource("jquery-1.8.2.min.js");
                String jqueryText = Resources.toString(jqueryUrl, Charsets.UTF_8);
                jse.executeScript(jqueryText);
                jse.executeScript("$("input.p-ui-textinputinputobject").val("Test");");

Comment: I not good in Jquery and added Jquery image in the topic. Could you check the code?